# how to copy variable to another graph in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I hope to copy tensorflow variable from an old graph to a new graph, then delete the old graph and make the new graph as default. Below is my code, but it raises an `AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'variable1'`. I am new to tensorflow. Can any one give me a specific example?

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

graph1 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    variable1 = tf.Variable(np.array([2.,-1.]), name='x1')
    initialize = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess1 = tf.Session(graph=graph1)
sess1.run(initialize)
print('sess1:',variable1.eval(session=sess1))

graph2 = tf.Graph()
with graph2.as_default():
    variable2 = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(graph1.variable1, graph2)
sess2 = tf.Session(graph=graph2)
#I want to remove graph1 and sess1, and make graph2 and sess2 the default here.
print('sess2:', variable2.eval(session=sess2))
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is depricated. Use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead.
2. You don't need `graph1.variable1`. Simply pass `variable1`.
3. You forgot to initialize variables in the second session:

   ```
   initialize2 = tf.global_variables_initializer()
   sess2=tf.Session(graph=graph2)
   sess2.run(initialize2)
   ```

So your code should be like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

graph1 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    variable1 = tf.Variable(np.array([2.,-1.]), name='x1')
    initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess1=tf.Session(graph=graph1)
    sess1.run(initialize)
    print('sess1:',variable1.eval(session=sess1))

graph2 = tf.Graph()
with graph2.as_default():
    variable2=tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(variable1,graph2)
    initialize2 = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess2=tf.Session(graph=graph2)
    sess2.run(initialize2)
    #I want to remove graph1 and sess1, ande make graph2 and sess2 as default here.
    print('sess2:',variable2.eval(session=sess2))
```

Comment: Does not work if Variable initial value is of initializer type