# Tensorflow: share weights between graphs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two graphs, each running with its own `tf.Session()`:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  sess = tf.Session()
  ...

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  sess = tf.Session()
  ...
```

is there a way to send variables and weights from one graph to another?

Comment: please check out these links:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894808/tensorflow-how-to-initialize-variables-on-another-graph and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273461/how-to-copy-variable-to-another-graph-in-tensorflow